# C++ _get_pgmptr function makes crash

Tags: c++

Let me refer to this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/24awhcba(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1

They're saying

> Returns zero if successful; an error code on failure. If pValue is
>   NULL, the invalid parameter handler is invoked as described in
>   Parameter Validation. **If execution is allowed to continue**, this
>   function sets errno to EINVAL and returns EINVAL.

But my program just died instead of returning errno. 
Is there anyone knows how to make program return errno?

Codes,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char* pPath;

if( _get_pgmptr(&pPath) != 0 )
    return false;
```

Comment: And what is your program doing? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: But the argument you pass is `&pPath` which can never be `NULL`,  and neither do `pPath` point to `NULL` (unless it's global variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something from your post, this is a CRT security feature that can be changed. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Most of the security-enhanced CRT functions and many of the preexisting functions validate their parameters. This could include checking pointers for NULL, checking that integers fall into a valid range, or checking that enumeration values are valid. When an invalid parameter is found, the invalid parameter handler is executed.
>
> The default invalid parameter **invokes Watson crash reporting**, which causes the application to crash and asks the user if they want to load the crash dump to Microsoft for analysis.

If you want to allow continuation after this instead of a crash, the solution is to set an *invalid parameter handler* using [_set_invalid_parameter_handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb(v=vs.100).aspx).

The example from MSDN adjusted for the use case in the question:

```
// crt_set_invalid_parameter_handler.c
// compile with: /Zi /MTd
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>  // For _CrtSetReportMode
#include <errno.h>

void myInvalidParameterHandler(const wchar_t* expression,
   const wchar_t* function, 
   const wchar_t* file, 
   unsigned int line, 
   uintptr_t pReserved)
{
   // it's a good idea to keep some logging here:
   printf("Invalid parameter detected in function %s."
            L" File: %s Line: %d\n", function, file, line);
   printf("Expression: %s\n", expression);
   // no abort
}


int main()
{
   _invalid_parameter_handler oldHandler, newHandler;
   newHandler = myInvalidParameterHandler;
   oldHandler = _set_invalid_parameter_handler(newHandler);

   // Disable the message box for assertions.
   _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, 0);

   _get_pgmptr(NULL);
   assert(EINVAL == errno());
   return 0;
}
```

However, keep in mind that this **globally applies to all parameter validation** in your program, so it is probably not a good idea. It would be much better to check the parameter before calling the function because that will leave the more secure parameter validation in place globally. You can achieve the same `errno` value this way:

```
if (pOut) 
{
    _get_pgmptr(pOut);
}
else
{
    _set_errno(EINVAL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me an example when the _pgmptr is null?

Comment: @yountae.kang I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

look at this..

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/245223/-get-pgmptr-bad-value-after-windows-10-update-to-1.html

It seems MS changed VC runtime after Win10 update.
for My Case, after the Update, 
With VS2010 _get_pgmptr() is fine.
With VS2015 it crash..

Instead of _get_pgmptr(), Use GetModuleFileName().